# how do i enter text in similar textboxs using sikuli

Tags: java, sikuli, sikuli-x

I am using sikuli and java for a citrix based webapplication. I am running in to multiple issues and not able to find documentation

How do i enter text in similar textboxs in sikuli ?
is there any option to choose textbox based on index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1-
to use **left/right/above/below** functions with the last match.

```
find("image.png")
m = getLastmatch().below().find("similar image1.png")
m.right().click("image3.png")
```

Option 2
Try to use" tab" while inputting data to avoid relying on images .
For example

```
Type(Key.Tab)
Type("username)
Type(key.tab)
Type("Password ")
```

Hope this helps